# Why is my email being sent through a strange hostname?

Tags: email, hostname

A client's email is handled by G Suite. When I check senderscore.org a strange sending IP and hostname (mail.jbsgroup.ie) appears amongst other Google-related hostnames. This particular domain belongs to another organisation in the locality. Can someone explain to me why is it appearing here and should I be worried?

https://www.senderscore.org/lookup.php?lookup=mullanlighting.com&validLookup=true

Comment: It is like that because someone did set it up like this.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: I agree, but at the same time, a little more detail could turn this into a very good learning opportunity for the person who asked the question.

Comment: @TomTom, yes I know the question is open-ended but in truth I'm not even sure what the desired outcome is. If there's something wrong here at all? It just seems strange to me (I've very little knowledge of email servers). I looked at senderscore.org after two emails were rejected by the receiving server (550 email blocked error). The hostname mail.jbsgroup.ie has the lowest sending score on that list. The solution I want is to ensure maximum email delivery. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to start looking at the emails that are sent through that server. It's highly probable that some entity within the company is using the server for some reason; it doesn't just happen all by itself.

Comment: @darren I think what most of us are trying to say is *dig IN MAN*

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending emails from web form? If yes, you might not be using SMTP authentication which is causing hostname and IP to be taken from the local mail server from you sent the email. You should use one your email account for SMTP authentication. The following are the settings you need to use in your script.

Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP username: Your full Gmail address (e.g. yourusername@gmail.com)
Gmail SMTP password: Your Gmail password
Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465
Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes

Comment: Emails from the website and internal software are all sent through Gmail SMTP. I wonder is there a way of checking whether any emails are being sent outside of this? DMARC?

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note is that your MX records ARE properly configured for G Suite. MX Toolbox is a great site to verify this on https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3amullanlighting.com&run=toolpage.

If you do not recognize or trust the mail.jbsgroup.ie hostname that appears to be sending mail on your client's behalf, then you can use SPF records to add a great layer of protection. SPF records will allow you to specify which servers are allowed to send mail from mullanlighting.com, and can also tell email recipients' servers to ignore all messages that are sent from anywhere else. For example, you might configure SPF records to identify Google's mail servers as the only authorized servers for your email domain.

Here is a link to Google's guide on how to "[Configure SPF records to work with G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723)."

Comment: SPF records are set up for G Suite. This can be verified using Google's Check MX tool - https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=mullanlighting.com&dkim_selector=. The only warning I'm getting on that is "There should not be a mail exchanger set up on naked domain name" which is probably totally unrelated? It's odd that mail.jbsgroup.ie would appear to be sending email on my client's behalf. It's just a regular, local company.